# Amazon post product in feed doesn't accept Size

Tags: laravel, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am sending Clothing product type to Amazon like this:

```
 <Clothing>
   <VariationData>
   <Parentage>child</Parentage>
   <Size>XS</Size>
   <Color>' . $amazonVariant->variant->color->name . '</Color>                                  
   <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
   </VariationData>
   <ClassificationData>
     <ClothingType>Accessory</ClothingType>
   </ClassificationData>
 </Clothing>
```

And sometimes it accepts Size and sometimes it doesn't, I don't understand why. What can be a problem, does anyone have example of sending Clothing to Amazon seller account.